# What does error code: POO13 mean?

Tags: cel, obd-ii, saturn, p0013

My vehicle: Saturn VUE 2008, 2WD 4Cylider. Checking light is steady on.
Read code at auto zone store, POO13.

The mileage is only 45K. I have no idea.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: You haven't had any problems or indications other than the check engine light? Has anything been changed before the check engine light went on?

Comment: Nothing changed and no problems found so far.

Comment: How many liters is your engine?

Comment: It is 2.4 liters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a site called [actron.com](http://www.actron.com/code_lookup.php) that describes OBDII codes.

[image: actron.com codes]

[Autozone](http://www.autozone.com/autozone/repairguides/Aura-Outlook-2007/Components-Systems/Camshaft-Position-Sensor-Actuator/_/P-0996b43f80cb0fea) explains what the camshaft position sensor is.

> **Camshaft Position Sensor Actuator**
>
> **Operation**
>
> The Camshaft Position (CMP) actuator is attached to each camshaft and
>   is hydraulically operated in order to change the angle of the camshaft
>   relative to Crankshaft Position (CKP). The CMP actuator solenoid is
>   controlled by the control module. The control module sends a pulse
>   width modulated 12-volt signal to a CMP actuator solenoid. The
>   solenoid controls the amount of engine oil flow to a CMP actuator. The
>   CMP actuator can change the camshaft angle a maximum of 25 degrees.
>   The control module increases the pulse width to accomplish the desired
>   camshaft operation.

It then goes into detail on how to remove and reinstall it.

> **Removal & Installation**
>
> **2.4L Engine**
>
> 1. Remove the intake manifold cover.
> 2. Disconnect the engine wiring harness electrical connector from the exhaust Camshaft Position (CMP) actuator solenoid valve, if required.
> 3. Disconnect the engine wiring harness electrical connector from the intake CMP actuator solenoid valve, if required.
> 4. Remove the exhaust CMP actuator solenoid valve bolt and valve, if required.
> 5. Remove the intake CMP actuator solenoid valve bolt and valve, if required.
> 6. Inspect the solenoid valve O-ring seals for damage, replace as necessary.
>
> **To install:**
>
> Installation is the reverse of removal, tighten the bolt to 89 in. lbs. (10 Nm).
>
> Lubricate the solenoid valve O-ring seals with clean engine oil.